# VB.net Excel adding theme format as table

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, excel

I am trying to figure out how to add a theme to my excel worksheet before saving it. I have found this code to change the cell color but have yet to find anything to change to a pre-default excel table format (the **Table style light 2** theme)

```
    With xlSheet.Range("A:D").Interior
        .Pattern = Excel.XlPattern.xlPatternLinearGradient
        .Gradient.Degree = 60
        .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear()

        With .Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
            .ThemeColor = Excel.XlThemeColor.xlThemeColorAccent1
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End With
```

How can i just select all the cells and place that **Table style light 2** onto them all using VB.net?

Any help would be great! Thanks! :o)

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it by using the following:

```
xlSheet.Range("Table1[#All]").Select()
xlSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight2"
```

David

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Selection.Style = "Style name"
```